# UIWebView in UITableViewCell only completes load in first cell

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I am using a UIWebView as the accessory view in each UITableViewCell in a UITable in order to display a tiny Openlayers map in each table view.  When I first display the table view, the UIWebView in the first cell displays the map fine, but the other UIWebViews in all the other cells are empty.

If I scroll the table up and down, then the other cells all load fine when they come back into view, each with the respective different little maps.

The UIWebViews each load an initial HMTL document on init, and this document includes the standard Openlayers ol.js javascript.

The accessory view UIView subclass is the delegate of the UIWebView and waits for it to load, before sending it another javascript to draw the map features.

Logging in this delegate method reveals that the web view `loaded` property is YES/TRUE, but the javascript `readyState` is still `loading`.

Why would this be?  How can I get this working as expected?

The webView is told to load the generic HTML/javascript via a call to `loadHTMLString:baseURL:` from within the `drawRect:` method.  Then the `webViewDidFinishLoad:` delegate method is used to check when loading is finished, so that the cell-specific javascript can be run after the generic HTML/javascript is complete.

The relevant code is:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSString *path = [NSBundle pathForResource:@"style" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];
    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path usedEncoding:nil error:nil];

    [_webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[path stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] isDirectory:YES]];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    if ( ! _webView.loading ) {
        if ( [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.readyState"] isEqualToString:@"complete"] ) {
            NSLog(@"All good");
            [self drawFeatures];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"ERROR:  webView loaded, readyState '%@'", [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.readyState"]);
            //[self performSelector:@selector(drawFeatures) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
        }
    }
}
```

( `[self drawFeatures]` assembles some javascript and sends it to the UIWebView to run, and it relies on the standard Openlayers (ol.js) javascript having completed in initial HTML web page.).

The output is:

```
2017-02-26 15:15:00.071 myapp[50443:25603667] ERROR:  webView loaded, readyState 'loading'
2017-02-26 15:15:00.093 myapp[50443:25603667] ERROR:  webView loaded, readyState 'loading'
2017-02-26 15:15:00.116 myapp[50443:25603667] ERROR:  webView loaded, readyState 'loading'
2017-02-26 15:15:00.132 myapp[50443:25603667] ERROR:  webView loaded, readyState 'loading'
2017-02-26 15:15:00.148 myapp[50443:25603667] ERROR:  webView loaded, readyState 'loading'
2017-02-26 15:15:00.166 myapp[50443:25603667] ERROR:  webView loaded, readyState 'loading'
2017-02-26 15:15:00.190 myapp[50443:25603667] ERROR:  webView loaded, readyState 'loading'
2017-02-26 15:15:00.208 myapp[50443:25603667] ERROR:  webView loaded, readyState 'loading'
2017-02-26 15:15:00.226 myapp[50443:25603667] ERROR:  webView loaded, readyState 'loading'
2017-02-26 15:15:00.245 myapp[50443:25603667] ERROR:  webView loaded, readyState 'loading'
2017-02-26 15:15:00.262 myapp[50443:25603667] ERROR:  webView loaded, readyState 'loading'
2017-02-26 15:15:00.292 myapp[50443:25603667] All good
```

As you can see from this output, the `isLoaded` state for most of the cells is true BEFORE `isLoaded` is true for the FIRST CELL (which comes up last after really truly being loaded and actually ready).  This implies that the web view thinks it's loaded when it's really not.

The loading error delegate method never gets called, so there appears to be no HTML/UIWebView errors:

```
-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"ERROR loading style view HTML:\n%@", [error description]);
}
```

Note that if I change the delegate method to check only the javascript `readyState`, and ignore the `isLoading` value, I never get a `readyState` of complete.  Just `loading`.  Presumably, this is because the web view things it is finished loading, and so this delegate method doesn't get called again.

**WORK AROUND THAT WORKS:**

I can work around the problem by uncommenting the `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` that is commented out in the delegate method above.  This indicates that the HTML does eventually load OK, but that the delegate method never gets called after it really is ready.

How can I get this to work as expected without resorting to a dodgy workaround of perform-with-delay?

**UPDATE TRYING AN ALTERNATIVE METHOD**

Here's another version of trying to get this working, based partly on the ideas from @Ricowere's answer (and similar to what I started with before going for the `drawRect:` hack

The HTML loading is now in my UIWebView subclass method.  In this case, the appropriate method is when I set a property of that UIWebView subclass:

```
- (void)setStyle:(RenderStyle *)style {
    _style = style;

    ...
    ...

    NSString *path = [NSBundle pathForResource:@"style" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];
    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path usedEncoding:nil error:nil];

    [self loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[path stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] isDirectory:YES]];
}
```

Then in the table view delegate, each time a table view cell is dequeued, add a UIWebView subclass view to it as an accessory view, and then for that UIWebView subclass view, call the property method that loads the HTML:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"styleCell"];

    if ( cell == nil ) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"styleCell"];
        ...
        ...
    }

    ...
    ...
    StyleViewUIWebViewSubclass *styleView = [[StyleViewUIWebViewSubclass alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    cell.accessoryView = styleView;

    styleView.style = [[RenderStyle alloc] initWithString:styles[styleName]];

    return cell;
}
```

However, this still has the same problem.  The perform-with-delay work around above is still required to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to some tips from @Ricowere I got this working.  My solution is based on the ideas from @Ricowere answer but using a UITableView delegate instead of a UITableViewCell subclass, and doing it all in Objective C instead of Swift.

Here's what ended up working for me...

In my WKWebView subclass:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if ( self = [super initWithFrame:frame] ) {
        ...
        self.navigationDelegate = self;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)setStyle:(RenderStyle *)style {
    _style = style;

    NSURL *url = [NSBundle URLForResource:@"style" withExtension:@"html" subdirectory:nil inBundleWithURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]];

    [self loadFileURL:url allowingReadAccessToURL:[url URLByDeletingLastPathComponent]];
}

- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation {
    [self drawFeatures];  //  This line runs the secondary instance-dependant javascript that relies on the generic javascript already having been completed
}
```

Then in my UITableViewDelegate:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"styleCell"];

    if ( cell == nil ) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"styleCell"];
        ...
        WKWebViewSubclass *styleView = [[WKWebViewSubclass alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

        cell.accessoryView = styleView;
    }

    ...
    ((WKWebViewSubclass *)cell.accessoryView).style = [[RenderStyle alloc] initWithString:styleString];

    return cell;
}
```

It seems to run a little slower than the UIWebView, which is odd, but at least it works without errors, and without any dodgy work arounds.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, remove the code you have in the drawRect. That approach is completely wrong, you're putting bussiness logic in a drawing method. (Which is executed once, and then the cells are reused)

Here, I show you a simple approach to tackle this.

```
class CellExample: UITableViewCell, UIWebViewDelegate {
    var accessoryWebView: UIWebView? {
        return accessoryView as? UIWebView
    }

    //If you're dequeuing the cell from IB.
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        // Set the frame you need or do this through autolayout.
        let webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
        accessoryView = webView
    }

    //You have to call this everytime a cell is dequeued 
    //(Then the content is properly displayed again.)
    func load(url: URL) {
        accessoryWebView?.delegate = self

        //Load the request or the HTML content as you need.

        //accessoryWebView?.loadHTMLString("whatever", baseURL: URL(string: "whatever")!)
//      accessoryWebView?.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url,
//                                               cachePolicy: .returnCacheDataElseLoad,
//                                               timeoutInterval: 10 ))
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()

        //If the cell is reused 'restart' the stack.
        accessoryWebView?.delegate = nil
        accessoryWebView?.stopLoading()
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        // Do the stuff you need about the javascript.
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah bollocks.... after awarding you 100 bounty points, I realised that I still had my perform-with-delay work around in place.  After removing this work around, it still doesn't work.  In fact it's a lot like what I started with before trying `drawRect:`.  See my UPDATE in my question to see what I'm trying now (not quite what you posted, but same idea, I think?).  I believe that the problem was, and still is, that the cell and its accessory view are not actually visible on screen when all this code is called, and UIWebView does not load HTML when not on screen.

Comment: The problem you had (the main one) is you have a limited functionality working with UIWebView and injecting Javascript. Use WKWebView instead. (This one will respect the DOM loading)
I've uploaded an open layers example working properly [here](https://gist.github.com/Ricowere/c247e17d64adc51c634ebf2bc63e56c7). Take a look this [post](http://nshipster.com/wkwebkit/) also. About the solution you've provided, please review it again because the way you're reusing the cells is incorrect. You're creating `StyleViewUIWebViewSubclass` every time rather than reusing it. Hope it helps definitely! :)

Comment: OK, it's working now, using WKWebView instead of UIWebView.  I was using UIWebView in order to grab its javascript context for debugging purposes (which I don't know if I can do with WKWebView, and it's much nicer than doing it all through Safari), but I now have my javascript down OK, so don't need that anymore.  The WKWebView is slow though... takes about 2 seconds before all the cells' contents are loaded.  But it will do.  I will post my solution as an answer just to show what I did.